# Default Schedulers for rxjava on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit to return rxjava Observable's for my async network calls.

I find myself repeating the following invocation:

`someApiCall().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

Seems like I'm always subscribing on the IO thread and observing on the Android main thread. This seems to be the best practice that all the resources I found advocate. Perhaps other than long-running computations, I don't quite understand when we would want to deviate from this pattern.

Is there a way to remove this boilerplate by defaulting the subscribeOn and observeOn threads?

Is this a use case for [rxjava plugins](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Plugins)? (I can't find many examples of their use.)

Can I set the default threads at the network boundary by messing with the [retrofit executors](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RestAdapter.Builder.html#setExecutors-java.util.concurrent.Executor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-)?

Comment: See my question/answer here for how to DRY this up a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25576177

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For `Observable` responses, Retrofit currently sets the `subscribeOn` as the HTTP executor of the `RestAdapter` (either provided or the default). This was done to shim RxJava support into the existing behavior.

The plan for 2.0 is to provide the ability to set defaults for both `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` explicitly (whether it be both, only one, or neither).

A reason you wouldn't want always want observation on the main thread is if you needed to chain multiple API calls together, for example.

Comment: in version 1.9, I found that not calling `subscribeOn(something)` (usually `Schedulers.io()`) during instrumentation tests deadlocks. Is that an expected behavior?

Answer (score 6):

The [Change Log](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of Retrofit Version 2.0.0-beta2 (2015-09-28) shows *subscribeOn()* is required for running in the background.

> Fix: Observable and Single-based execution of requests now behave synchronously (and thus requires subscribeOn() for running in the background).

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, it's possible to remove both calls.

Here is the retrofit adapter class that automatically schedules both `subscribeOn` and `observedOn` to remove the need for the boilerplate calls in each invocation:

```
public class RxThreadingCallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {
    private final RxJava2CallAdapterFactory original;

    private RxThreadingCallAdapterFactory() {
        // Always call on background thread
        original = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());
    }

    public static CallAdapter.Factory create() {
        return new RxThreadingCallAdapterFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public CallAdapter<?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new RxCallAdapterWrapper(original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit));
    }

    private static class RxCallAdapterWrapper implements CallAdapter<Observable<?>> {
        private final CallAdapter<?> wrapped;

        public RxCallAdapterWrapper(CallAdapter<?> wrapped) {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        @Override
        public Type responseType() {
            return wrapped.responseType();
        }

        @Override
        public <R> Observable<?> adapt(Call<R> call) {
            Observable observable = (Observable) wrapped.adapt(call);

            // Always handle result on main thread
            return observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this adapter when configuring retrofit:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(...)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxThreadingCallAdapterFactory.create())
```

I wrote [this blog post](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/rxjava-retrofit-threading-call-adapter) that goes into a lot of detail on exactly what's happening here.

This will remove both calls, which I consider boilerplate. I consider Jake's scenario of chaining together background calls to not really apply, because in this case I would do retrofit synchronous calls and not use schedulers at all.

Answer (score 3):

it is not the full answer to what you are looking for, but this at least removes the burden of righting `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`

```
retrofit = new Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .baseUrl(app.getUrlBase())
            .client(httpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(
RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()) // <-- default subscribeOn() 
)
                .addConverterFactory(jsonFactory)
                .build();
```