# Using subscribeOn with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

There is conflicting information about when and whether to use `subscribeOn` with Retrofit.

[Here is an answer](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/430#issuecomment-37068797) saying to not use `subscribeOn`.
[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788838/default-schedulers-for-rxjava-on-android/24809186#24809186) seeming to imply that `subscribeOn` has no good default set.
[Here is example code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/u2020/data/GalleryDatabase.java#L77) using `subscribeOn`.

So, once for for all, when should I use `subscribeOn` and with what thread?  What are the possible ramifications of using or not using `subscribeOn`?

```
apiService.issueRequest()
    // Is this useful? Required? Bad practice?
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    // Do actions on main thread
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Response>() {
        @Override public void call(Response response) {
            handleResponse(response);
    });
```

Comment: When i mixed these two libraries I opted to keep them separate. Retrofit just wraps the return in a `Observable` so I do that myself. This allows me to have both async (for the app) and synch (for testing) APIs.

Comment: One area where using `subscribeOn` with retrofit is extremely helpful is in a request interceptor. For example, if you need to decorate a header with an auth token, often you have to fetch those in a background thread. GoogleAuthUtil, for example, will blow up if a token is requested on the main thread. Hopefully that won't always be the case to avoid the extra wrapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the current version of Retrofit (1.9.0), Retrofit use his own executor to perform the http call and don't use [the executor backed by the schedulers](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/ead72edbb91343bd9fd8db5636e44f9af7bbcafc/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RxSupport.java#L42) given by the `subscribeOn` method.

In your case, the scheduler will be used only to execute the code that will add your http call to the executor used by retrofit. (So it's a bit useless...)

**BUT**, regarding the actual code from [Retrofit on Github](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RxSupport.java), retrofit stop to use his executor, so it may be possible to used a RxJava scheduler instead.